# How to graph API search fan page post

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to use the graph search to search for some keywords that are posted by a page?

I was trying http://graph.facebook.com//search?q= but it only returns the page info without content.

Comment: As mainly we used `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=SEARCH_QUERY&type=OBJECT_TYPE` this format for search

Comment: I need to be able to search for a specific page content.